# Unable to connect to remote MySql server in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, web-applications

I needed to connect to MYSQL databases via asp.net. I am using MySQL Connector to make connection with database but while doing this I am having this Error:[image]

```
Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/old-style-passwords-settings-when-using-mysql-5-x-150333.html)?

Comment: My Connection String is like:
<add name="AddAgent" connectionString="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Database=DBName; Uid=UserID; Pwd=Password;"
      providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MySQL 4.1 and higher they use a new protocol that is not compatible with earlier versions.  Which is why when you upgrade the server from an earlier version to 4.1 or higher you receive the authentication error message.

If you need to connect to the database with both clients before and after version 4.1 you must have two passwords stored. One the old way and one the new way.

You can set a users password to the new way using:

```
SET PASSWORD for <username> = PASSWORD('new password')
SET PASSWORD FOR 'steve'@'10.15.2.67' = PASSWORD('my secure password');
```

If needed you can also set passwords to the old way using:

```
SET PASSWORD for <username> = OLD_PASSWORD('new password')
SET PASSWORD FOR 'steve'@'10.15.2.67' = OLD_PASSWORD('my secure password');
```

There is a great page in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) which will detail the process

You can actually for the server if newer than 4.1 to still use the old password method however **this isn't recommended**.

To do this, you can start the server with the [--old-passwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_old-passwords) option.

So, either the server has updated and you're using a old client - or you've updated your client (which now uses the new password system) and your connecting to a server below 4.1

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I am connecting to live database. How i be able to change my password on live?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk you're right, I was being lazy. I've updated my answer to be an actual answer not really a comment with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok but if you do not have the authorization to do this,simply because you are in a shared hosting environment:

```
SET PASSWORD for <username> = OLD_PASSWORD('new password')
SET PASSWORD FOR 'steve'@'10.15.2.67' = OLD_PASSWORD('my secure password');
```

What can you do?
I have not found a workaround and my hosting provider has changed the mysql configuration without warning...nor giving solutions.

UNCOMPLETE SOLUTION
You can force the web.config to use the old connector. It seems to work, but mysql errors occur... so I think there is a bug somewhere in the connectors.