# Aspx C# MySQL connection string not connecting using web.Config

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-config

I am not an expert by any means with C# and asp but I have managed to make it to the end of my site and deploy.  Everything works fine locally including the MySQL connection.  However when I plug in the connection string given by my host I get error messages.  I have looked everywhere to find a solution and even contacted the host who was no help at all.  I'm so frustrated and I know the best of the best are here.  I'm sure there is a more than one issue with all my code.  I was basic HTML and JS and SQL up until like 3 weeks ago.  Than you everyone.

***Web.Config file***

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
 <add name="mySQLconn" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=skyhill.ipowermysql.com; user id=skyhillweb; password=******; database=skyhill; OPTION=3;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   <compilation debug="true"/>
   <authentication mode="None"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
     <files>
       <add value="/pages/default.aspx"/>
     </files>
   </defaultDocument>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Here is the page (just a test page)  the path is pages/abc.aspx is you want to see the error.***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="gridAgent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:TextBox ID="MessageBox" runat="server">
   </asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

***and here is the C# behind the page***

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SkhillWebApp.pages
{
   public partial class abc : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySQLconn"].ConnectionString);
         string strSQL = "SELECT agentID, FirstName, LastName FROM agent";
         conn.Open();
         MySqlDataAdapter mydata = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);
         MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydata);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         mydata.Fill(ds);

         gridAgent.DataSource = ds;
         gridAgent.DataBind();
         conn.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

And this is the code provided by my host to connect to the MySQL database.

```
Start
<% 
Dim ConnectionString 
ConnectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=skyhill.ipowermysql.com; PORT=3306;" &_
"DATABASE=skyhill; USER=skyhillweb; PASSWORD=*password*; OPTION=3;"
%>
' End
```

Comment: What _are_ the error messages you are receiving?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you cannot use the MySqlClient classes with an ODBC driver. Have you tried your original connectionstring adapted to the different parameters provided by your ISP?

Comment: @Brian thank you for replying - here is the error     Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: driver
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: driver

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure what you mean.  I sort of understand the driver vs the classes.  The second part I def do not understand.  Thank you for replying.

Comment: @aaron - This `ConnectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};` is your issue.  Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: I mean, the connection string provided by your ISP is valid for ODBC classes like OdbcConnection, OdbcCommand etc... not for MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand.... so, unless you want to recode your program to make use of the Odbc classes you need to change that connection string applying the syntax used for the MySqlClient classes see [connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)

Comment: @Brian yes this is what iPower gave to my as an asp connection string.

Comment: @Steve Ok this makes sense.  I played with some of these yesterday and I could not find one that worked.  Sorry by these I mean the MySql Connection string.  I got password errors like the one that I get now.   Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.

Comment: You should use some kind of management tool for mySql ([phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) should be provided by your ISP) and then issue the commands required to update the password to the new format See this [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html) page for details

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the 'Driver' parameter of the connection string your host provided. Try this in your web.config, adapted from the mysql connector [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html).

```
<add name="mySQLconn" connectionString="Server=skyhill.ipowermysql.com;Database=skyhill;Uid=skyhillweb;Pwd=yourpassword;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Comment: @Brian the change in the Web.Config returned this error.   Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.

Comment: @aaron - See the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295541/unable-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server-in-asp-net) post for information on the error you are now receiving.

Comment: @Brian you beat me by 15 seconds!

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian.  I came across this yesterday but it didn't make much sense to me at all.  Where do I put those SET commands to make this change in format?

Comment: It seems to me that you would have to set them at the DB-level _and then_ try to connect with your application.

Comment: @Brian the host that we use for the MySQL database doesn't even allow me to run a stored procedure.  It's one of those myPHP mySQL ordeals which isn't going to allow to do that.  I will double check that but I'm pretty positive.  Thank you again for so much help.  What is my alternative?  How would I migrate to the ODBC classes so their connection string will work?

Comment: @aaron - I am afraid that I am running out of suggestions for you.  It has been YEARS since I have worked for any length of time with MySql.  Is there a network admin on your end that you could work with?

Comment: @Brian Hahaha.  It's been a few weeks since I've been  "blessed" with mySQL (sense my sarcasm?  LOL) I'm a SQL guy.  And since they are trying to avoid an outward facing application in house they opted to go with a basci hosted mySQL db.  Do I just need to recode using the ODBC classes?

Comment: @aaron - I would do just that just to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old version of the MySQL dll for .Net, it's solve the problem.